# Neo4j - How to extend labels with variable values?

Tags: neo4j

I wanted to update more than 1 node in single query. I have a problem with labels update.

```
WITH [
    {
        code: "AAA",
        secondprop: "val1",
        labels: [
            "label1",
            "label2"
        ]
    },
    {
        code: "BBB",
        secondprop: "val2",
        labels: [
            "label3",
            "label4"
        ]
    }
] as batch
UNWIND batch as row
MERGE (n:EI:EI_CURRENT{code: row.code})
ON CREATE SET n={uuid: apoc.create.uuid()}
SET n += row
WITH n as nn, apoc.text.join(row.labels,':') as labels
SET nn:labels
REMOVE nn.labels 
return nn;
```

In attached query, I used some kind of workaround - I added labels for each node as value of property `labels`, and then I'm trying to join them via `apoc` statement and set to node.

Unfortunately this query sets just one label named `labels` for every nodes in batch...

I also tried to use `CALL apoc.create.setLabels(nn, nn.labels)`, but this statement overrides labels, not extends them (I don't know what labels are currently in nodes to update, but definitely I don't want to override them)

Is there any way to update labels for each nodes separately?

Comment: Can you provide some sample output of what are you getting and what is expected?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `apoc.create.setLabels` using `apoc.create.addLabels` like this:

```
WITH [
    {
        code: "AAA",
        secondprop: "val1",
        labels: [
            "label1",
            "label2"
        ]
    },
    {
        code: "BBB",
        secondprop: "val2",
        labels: [
            "label3",
            "label4"
        ]
    }
] as batch
UNWIND batch as row
MERGE (n:EI:EI_CURRENT{code: row.code})
ON CREATE SET n={uuid: apoc.create.uuid()}
SET n += row
WITH n as nn, apoc.text.join(row.labels,':') as labels
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(nn, [labels]) YIELD node return node
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work - `addLabels()` works quite similar to `setLabels()` and I'm losing already existing labels after calling those methods.

Comment: Try running the above query here http://console.neo4j.org/, seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with following query:

```
CALL apoc.create.setLabels(nn, labels(nn) + nn.labels)
```

We just need to merge already existing labels (`labels(nn)`) with newly created labels from batch.